# jquery animation ignoring duration

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm just getting into jquery, and I'm having a bit of an issue with some animations. I want a div to grow and shrink alternately on a button press. When the button is pressed the first time. the div shrinks properly, taking 500 ms to complete. However, when the button is pressed again, the div grows instantly, regardless of the fact that I set it to take 500 ms. I have no idea what my issue could be here.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
  {
   $("#Change").click(function()
     {
       if (!$("#displayable").is(".hidden"))
         {
           $("#displayable").animate({height:"0px"},500).addClass("hidden");
         } else {
           $("#displayable").animate({height:"100%"},500).removeClass("hidden");
         }
     });
  });
</script>

<div style="margin-top:8px; margin-bottom:8px;">
     <p><button id="Change">Change Div Size</button></p>
</div> 

<div class="main" id="displayable" style="display:block; overflow=hidden;">

     [other children elements]

</div>
```

I can tell that when the animate command is growing the div, it does spend the full duration doing something, because if I set it to something very huge, I can't then reshrink the div until the growing animation has "finished", even though it visually popped up immediately.

**EDIT:** As per atmd suggested, the solution is to not use 100% when resetting the height. This necessitated getting the height before it was shrunk and resizing back to that height after.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
  {
   $("#Change").click(function()
     {
       if (!$("#displayable").is(".hidden"))
         {
           $height = $("#displayable").height();  
           $("#displayable").animate({height:"0px"},500).addClass("hidden");
         } else {
           $("#displayable").animate({height:$height + 'px'},500).removeClass("hidden");
         }
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504755/animating-a-div-to-100-height      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792302/animate-jquery-height-percentage    these might help

Comment: This has been useful, thank you. I didn't even think to change the 100% to test if that was the issue. I'll figure out how to fix this in my code and post my solution.